# How to fix "Bad credentials" error using authentication manager?

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, jwt

I'm doing a project in which you have to register some users and also giving them a rol (user by default). After I've registered a user, I added  jwt auth and I was able to get the jwt response, but after trying to implement some filters on it, the code started to fail.

At this point I've commented the filter implementation method and also inside my WebSecurityConfig.

It's supposed that I'll receive a username and password inside my endpoint ("authenticate/").

```
@RequestMapping(
            value = {"authenticate", "authenticate/"},
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = {
                    MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE,
                    MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
                    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
            },
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    public @ResponseBody AuthResponse login(AuthRequest authRequest) throws Exception
    {
        return this.authService.authenticate(authRequest);
    }
```

AuthRequest is username and password.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
public class AuthResponse
{
    private String username;
    private String password;
}
```

But the error is when I try to authenticate the user using the AuthenticationManager.

AuthService authenticate method

```
public AuthResponse authenticate(AuthRequest authRequest) throws Exception
    {
        //System.out.println(authRequest.getUsername() +"," + authRequest.getPassword() + "," + this.bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(authRequest.getPassword()));
        try {
            this.authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authRequest.getUsername(), authRequest.getPassword())
            );
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            //Here is the error
            throw new Exception("Incorrect username or password", e);
        }

        final UserDetails userDetails = usersDetailService.loadUserByUsername(authRequest.getUsername());
        final String jwt = jwtUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
        //this.logService.save(new Log(null, userDetails.getUsername(), jwt, null));
        System.out.println(jwt);
        return new AuthResponse(jwt);
    }
```

Error inside postman console.

```
"timestamp": "2021-04-03T19:23:01.510+00:00",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "trace": "java.lang.Exception: Incorrect username or password\n\tat com.cncipo.nl.auth.service.AuthService.authenticate2(AuthService.java:60)\n\tat com.cncipo.nl.controller.SessionRestController.auth(SessionRestController.java:85)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\nCaused by: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials\n\tat org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:141)\n\tat org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182)\n\tat org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201)\n\tat org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:518)\n\tat com.cncipo.nl.auth.service.AuthService.authenticate2(AuthService.java:56)\n\t... 86 more\n",
    "message": "Access Denied",
    "path": "/api/authenticate"
}
```

I'll add the WebSecurityConfig and the JwtFilter in case there is something that I missed and it's causing the error.

JwtFilter

```
//@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter
{

    @Autowired
    private UsersDetailService usersDetailService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        /* Get the header for auth */
        final String authHeader =  request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String username = null;
        String jwt = null;

        System.out.println("Flag of header it's null when I implemented" + authHeader);

        /* Extract jwt and username */
        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer "))
        {
            jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
            username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwt);
        }

        /* Extract user details */
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null)
        {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.usersDetailService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            if (jwtUtil.validateToken(jwt, userDetails))
            {
                /* Create default new jwt auth token */
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        /* Handling the control to the next filter chain */
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfig

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Autowired
    private UsersDetailService usersDetailService;

    //@Autowired
    //private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.userDetailsService(usersDetailService);
    }

    /* Bean of AuthManager due to it used to work in older version of spring */
    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception
    {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        /* Disable security */
        http.csrf().disable();

        /* User info page requires login as admin and user role. If no login, redirect */
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("users").access("hasAnyRole('admin', 'user')");

        /* Only for admin */
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("logs", "admin").access("hasRole('admin')");

        /* The pages does not require login/auth */
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("login", "logout", "/authenticate/, login/")
                .permitAll();//.anyRequest().authenticated();

        /* Using sessiong managment for intercept jwt auth . Spring won't create session, jwt will manage them*/
        //http.exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        //http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
}
```

UsersDetailService, MyUserDetails implements UserDetails from **import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;**

```
@Service
public class UsersDetailService implements UserDetailsService
{
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException
    {
        User user = this.userRepository.getUserByUsername_user(username);

        if (user == null) { throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find user"); }
        return new MyUserDetails(user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following settings:

> In your SecurityConfig

```
 @Autowired
    private JwtFilterRequest jwtFilterRequest;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()           
            .antMatchers("/forgetPassword").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/registerUser").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/index.html").failureUrl("/login?error")
            .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout");

    http.addFilterBefore(this.jwtFilterRequest, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

> Filter Class JWT (JwtFilterRequest):

```
import cl.project.admin.security.jwt.JwtUtil;
import cl.project.admin.security.service.CustomUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;    
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class JwtFilterRequest extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            String jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            String username = this.jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwt);

            if(username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null){
                UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

                if(this.jwtUtil.validateToken(jwt, userDetails)){
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                    authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
                }
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

> Your Custom UserDetailService:

```
import cl.project.admin.controllers.AttentionController;
import cl.project.admin.models.dao.IUserDao;
import cl.project.admin.models.entity.User;
import cl.project.admin.models.service.UserServiceImpl;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomUserDetailsService.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserServiceImpl userService;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userService.findByUsername(username);

        if(user == null) {
            this.logger.error("Error al ingresar: " + username);
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }


        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>());
    }
}
```

> JWT Util

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;

@Service
public class JwtUtil {
    
    @Value("${keyJWTSpringSecurity}")
    private static final String KEY = "passwordInYourApplicationProperties";


    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetail){
        return Jwts.builder().setSubject(userDetail.getUsername()).setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000*60*60*5))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, KEY).compact();
    }

    public String extractUsername(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }
    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(KEY).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }

    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    public String generateToken(String username) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        return createToken(claims, username);
    }

    public String generateTokenInfinity(String username) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        return createTokenInfinity(claims, username);
    }

    private String createToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {

        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 5))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, KEY).compact();
    }

    private String createTokenInfinity(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {

        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 800))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, KEY).compact();
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = extractUsername(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Alex! I just have one doubt. How can I limit some endpoints (users, admin, etc) just for admin role?

And if leave this **permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()** I got a 403 unauthorized error and my  authorizationHeader is still null.